# What is causing this error (ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'High')?

Tags: python, string, csv

I don't know how to fix the error (ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'High'). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
high = 0

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:

            if float(line[2]) > high:
                high = float(line[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your CSV has a header row, so the column value in the first row is the string "High", which can't be converted to a number. Just skip the first row in that case by calling `next(csv_reader)` before your `for` loop.